# Not allowed to Mock Final Object

Tags: java, mockito

I have a final class called 'Color`

I'm trying to use it as below but it fails with assert exception that "Null comparison is failed with 'sendEvent'

```
@Mock
private SendEvent sendEvent;
```

But my assertion is failing for null check, why and how I can handle this ?

```
@Test
public void testFirst() {
        when(myPublisher.publishEvent(any(EventTypes.class), any(Color.class)))
        .thenReturn(sendEvent);
        assertEquals(myPublisher.publishEvent(any(EventTypes.class), any(Color.class)), sendEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: There is no way this compiles: `public Final enum Color`

Comment: Sorry, updated the question

Comment: The problem is with the last line. You need to call your method with an actual EventTypes instance, and an actual Color instance. `any` can't be used there. It's actually equivalent to `assertEquals(myPublisher.publishEvent(null, null), sendEvent);`, since any returns null. And that test fails. What's the point in testing a method that you mocked? This will test Mockito, not your code.

Comment: Do you run the tests with the Mockito runner (JUnit 4) or extension (JUnit 5)? I'm not sure what it looks like for JUnit 4, but in JUnit 5 you'd need `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` (on the class or method, depending on needed scope) for the `@Mock` annotation to work.